# How to use evaluateOnNewDocument and exposeFunction?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Recently, I used Puppeteer for a new project.

I have a few questions about thea part of the API I don't understand. The documentation is very simple for these API introductions:

1. `page.exposeFunction`
2. `page.evaluateOnNewDocument`

**Can I have a detailed demo to gain a better understanding?**

Answer (score 2):

#### Summary:

The Puppeteer function [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) essentially allows you to access Node.js functionality within the Page DOM Environment.

On the other hand, [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args) evaluates a predefined function when a new document is created and before any of its scripts are executed.

---

The [Puppeteer Documentation for `page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) states:

> #### page.exposeFunction(name, puppeteerFunction)
>
> - `name` <[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)> Name of the function on the window object
> - `puppeteerFunction` <[function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)> Callback function which will be called in Puppeteer's context.
> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)>
>
> The method adds a function called `name` on the page's `window` object. When called, the function executes `puppeteerFunction` in node.js and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which resolves to the return value of `puppeteerFunction`.
>
> If the `puppeteerFunction` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), it will be awaited.
>
> > **NOTE** Functions installed via `page.exposeFunction` survive navigations.
>
> An example of adding an `md5` function into the page:
>
> ```
> const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
> const crypto = require('crypto');
>
> puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
>   const page = await browser.newPage();
>   page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));
>   await page.exposeFunction('md5', text =>
>     crypto.createHash('md5').update(text).digest('hex')
>   );
>   await page.evaluate(async () => {
>     // use window.md5 to compute hashes
>     const myString = 'PUPPETEER';
>     const myHash = await window.md5(myString);
>     console.log(`md5 of ${myString} is ${myHash}`);
>   });
>   await browser.close();
> });
> ```
>
> An example of adding a `window.readfile` function into the page:
>
> ```
> const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
> const fs = require('fs');
>
> puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
>   const page = await browser.newPage();
>   page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));
>   await page.exposeFunction('readfile', async filePath => {
>     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>       fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, text) => {
>         if (err)
>           reject(err);
>         else
>           resolve(text);
>       });
>     });
>   });
>   await page.evaluate(async () => {
>     // use window.readfile to read contents of a file
>     const content = await window.readfile('/etc/hosts');
>     console.log(content);
>   });
>   await browser.close();
> });
> ```

---

Furthermore, the [Puppeteer Documentation for `page.evaluateOnNewDocument`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args) explains:

> #### page.evaluateOnNewDocument(pageFunction, ...args)
>
> - `pageFunction` <[function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)|[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)> Function to be evaluated in browser context
> - `...args` <...[Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)> Arguments to pass to `pageFunction`
> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)>
>
> Adds a function which would be invoked in one of the following scenarios:
>
> - whenever the page is navigated
> - whenever the child frame is attached or navigated. In this case, the function is invoked in the context of the newly attached frame
>
> The function is invoked after the document was created but before any of its scripts were run. This is useful to amend the JavaScript environment, e.g. to seed `Math.random`.
>
> An example of overriding the navigator.languages property before the page loads:
>
> ```
> // preload.js
>
> // overwrite the `languages` property to use a custom getter
> Object.defineProperty(navigator, "languages", {
>   get: function() {
>     return ["en-US", "en", "bn"];
>   }
> });
>
> // In your puppeteer script, assuming the preload.js file is in same folder of our script
> const preloadFile = fs.readFileSync('./preload.js', 'utf8');
> await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(preloadFile);
> ```

Comment: Is copy and pasting the documentation considered an answer?

Comment: @mawburn was about to write the same.