# How to pass a function in Puppeteers .evaluate() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

Whenever I try to pass a function, like this:

```
var myFunc = function() { console.log("lol"); };

await page.evaluate(func => {
 func();
 return true;
}, myFunc);
```

I get:

```
(node:13108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: func is not a function
at func (<anonymous>:9:9)
(node:13108) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Why? How to do it correctly?

Thank you!

€: let me clarify: I am doing it this way because I want to find some DOM elements first and use them inside of that function, more like this (simplified):

```
var myFunc = function(element) { element.innerHTML = "baz" };

await page.evaluate(func => {
  var foo = document.querySelector('.bar');
  func(foo);
  return true;
}, myFunc);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I dynamically inject functions to evaluate using Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207414/how-can-i-dynamically-inject-functions-to-evaluate-using-puppeteer)

Answer (score 70):

You cannot pass a function directly into `page.evaluate()`, but you can call another special method (`page.exposeFunction`), which expose your function as a global function (also available in as an attribute of your page `window` object), so you can call it when you are inside `page.evaluate()`:

```js
var myFunc = function() { console.log("lol"); };
await page.exposeFunction("myFunc", myFunc);

await page.evaluate(async () => {
   await myFunc();
   return true;
});
```

Just remember that `page.exposeFunction()` will make your function return a `Promise`, then, you need to use `async` and `await`. This happens because your function will not be [running inside your browser](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction), but inside your `nodejs` application.

1. [exposeFunction() does not work after goto()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2170)
2. [Why can't I access 'window' in an exposeFunction() function with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281130/why-cant-i-access-window-in-an-exposefunction-function-with-puppeteer)
3. [How to use evaluateOnNewDocument and exposeFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113267/how-to-use-evaluateonnewdocument-and-exposefunction)
4. [exposeFunction remains in memory?](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3961)
5. [Puppeteer: pass variable in .evaluate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/puppeteer-pass-variable-in-evaluate)
6. [Puppeteer evaluate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904333/puppeteer-evaluate-function)
7. [allow to pass a parameterized funciton as a string to page.evaluate](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/982)
8. [Functions bound with page.exposeFunction() produce unhandled promise rejections](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3549)
9. [exposed function queryseldtcor not working in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772855/exposed-function-queryseldtcor-not-working-in-puppeteer)
10. [How can I dynamically inject functions to evaluate using Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207414/how-can-i-dynamically-inject-functions-to-evaluate-using-puppeteer)

Comment: How can I pass a map to a js function?

Comment: @Alston Which map do you mean? A Map data structure or an array map? If a Map data structure, you have to [serialize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153172/how-to-serialize-a-map-in-javascript).

Answer (score 25):

Similar problems have been discussed in a puppeteer [issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/982).

There are several way to deal with your problem. First rule is to keep it simple.

## Evaluate the function

This is the fastest way to do things, you can just pass the function and execute it.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  var myFunc = function(element) { element.innerHTML = "baz" };
  var foo = document.querySelector('.bar');
  myFunc(foo);
  return true;
});
```

## Expose the function beforehand

You can expose the function beforehand using a page.evaluate, or a page.addScriptTag

```
// add it manually and expose to window
await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.myFunc = function(element) { element.innerHTML = "baz" };
});

// add some scripts
await page.addScriptTag({path: "myFunc.js"});

// Now I can evaluate as many times as I want
await page.evaluate(() => {
  var foo = document.querySelector('.bar');
  myFunc(foo);
  return true;
});
```

## Use ElementHandle

### page.$(selector)

You can pass an element handle to .evaluate and make changes as you seem fit.

```
const bodyHandle = await page.$('body');
const html = await page.evaluate(body => body.innerHTML, bodyHandle);
```

### page.$eval

You can target one element and make changes as you want.

```
const html = await page.$eval('.awesomeSelector', e => {
e.outerHTML = "whatever"
});
```

The trick is to [read the docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md) and keep it simple.

Comment: What's the point of first solution, *you can just pass the function and execute it.*? What if we want to use the same `myFunc` in multiple `evaluate` calls?

Comment: like the answer below says, you can't pass a function into the page like you can a variable using `page.evaluate`. ex: `await page.evaluate(async func =>{ /* ... */  }, myFunc)` <-- does not work

Answer (score 4):

**Pass function with parameter**

// add it manually and expose to window

```
 await page.evaluate(() => {
      window.myFunc = function(element) { element.innerHTML = "baz" };
    });
```

// and then call function declared above

```
 await page.evaluate((param) => {
         myFunc (param);
    }, param);
```

Comment: I am not supposed to call `window.myFunc` instead of `myFunc` inside `page.evaluate(...)`? How `myFunc` ended up in the global namespace after being assigned to `window.myFunc`?

Comment: How you answer is different from the most voted answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
//  External function to run inside evaluate context
function getData() {
        return document.querySelector('title').textContent;
    }

function mainFunction(url, extractFunction){
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
    let page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url);

    let externalFunction = Object.assign(extractFunction);

    let res = await this.page.evaluate(externalFunction)

    console.log(res);
}
    

// call it here
mainFunction('www.google.com',getData);
```

Comment: Nice one, this actually worked

Answer (score 0):

I like [evaluateOnNewDocument](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluateonnewdocument/) because I want to ensure my script code is ran before anything else.

For example, if looking for total-blocking-time web vitals:

```js
  const perfObserver = () => {
    // Important that you don't run for this URL.
    if (window.location.href === 'about:blank') return;

    window.totalBlockingTime = 0;

    console.log(window.location.href);
    console.log('TBT', totalBlockingTime);

    const observer = new PerformanceObserver(function (list) {
      let perfEntries = list.getEntries();
      for (const perfEntry of perfEntries) {
        let longtask = perfEntry.duration - 50
        if (longtask) console.log(perfEntry);
        totalBlockingTime += longtask;
      }
      console.log({ totalBlockingTime });
    });
    observer.observe({ type: "longtask", buffered: true });
  };


  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    devtools: false
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(perfObserver);

  await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/");

  const performance = await page.evaluate(() => window.totalBlockingTime);
  
  console.log(performance);

  await browser.close();
```

You can also pass arguments into the function from your parent scope. See docs link above.