# How to serialize a Map in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So...there is this type in js called `Map` and it is really nice...it is faster than an Object for iterations and calculations so I really like it. However...you can't pass Maps around as you could with objects.

I know that I could turn Map into JSON but it is costly to do so and it kind of looses the point of using Maps in the first place.

JSON format is not meant for Maps...it was meant for Objects.

So...lets move from the JSON format a little.

Is there a way for me to serialize a `Map` into a string in any way so that I can then do the opposite - from said serialized `Map` to end up with a `Map`

Preferably this method should be as easy to perform as `JSON.stringify` or its counterpart `JSON.parse`.

I want to use `Map` as it is faster and better but I need to send my data as string. The format of the string is not important as long as I can parse it back into a `Map`

Comment: you said that you can turn Map into JSON, why not Map -> JSON -> String?

Comment: because turning it into JSON in the first place is a slow process and it makes it more costly over all to use Map than an Object even though a Map is faster to iterate over and do calculations. Also turning it into JSON means to turn it into a string.

Comment: Native javascript doesn't have any inbuilt serializer. You need use some good library for javascript.

Comment: You could use `JSON.stringify([...map.entries()])` for serializing and `new Map(JSON.parse(string))` for parsing. That’s the only way you could serialize maps: turning it into a string. I’m not exactly sure what you mean by _“you can’t pass Maps around as you could with objects”_.

Comment: Well....the thing with this approach is that it relies on JSON standard...and it is slow. Map.entries returns a new array for each value...so if you have 1000 values....you end up with 1000 arrays..and then you JSON every single one of them...this way is soo slow it makes it useless to use Maps in the first place. I am asking for a way to turn it into a string without using the JSON format..any other format will suffice as long as it doesnt create N new arrays and stringify every single one of them. It works but it makes it useless to use Maps

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is a native way of doing this in Javascript.

the Map object has a method called entries() that returns an iterator that will yield each entry in the map as an array with 2 values in it. It will look like [key, value].

To avoid writing any looping code yourself, you can use `Array.from()` which can consume an iterator and extract each item from it. Having that, the following will give you your Map object in a serialized form.

```javascript
let mySerialMap = JSON.stringify(Array.from(myMap.entries()))
console.log(mySerialMap)
```

Now, that's not even the coolest part. But before getting there, let me show you one possible way of using the `Map` constructor.

```javascript
let original = new Map([
  ['key1', 'the-one-value']
  ['second-key', 'value-two']
])
```

The array of arrays that you see being passed to the `Map` object is in the same format as what you get from using `Array.from(myMap.entries())`.

So you could rebuild your map in a single line using the following sample code:

```javascript
let myMap = new Map(JSON.parse(mySerialMap))
```

Then, you could use `myMap` as you would any `Map`:

```javascript
let myMap = new Map(JSON.parse(mySerialMap))
let first = myMap.get('some-key')
myMap.set('another-key', 'some value')
```

Comment: Beware: If you have a key that is undefined, after serialize and deserialize the key will be null. So it is better to use null instead of undefined as key.

Comment: @EgemenÇiftci, can you provide an example of what you are stating?

Comment: At the very beginning of your script, you start with a line of comment saying `// Create a map with an undefined key`. Honestly, who does that in normal everyday life? That defeat the entire purpose of the Map object in Javascript. The key is the only way to identify the value stored in a Map. Can you give me a valid use case for having a key that is undefined in a map?

Comment: Javascript does allow a lot of non sense. But it doesn't mean that we should use them. If you want to know more about some of them, check https://medium.com/javascript-non-grata/the-top-10-things-wrong-with-javascript-58f440d6b3d8. For example, you will see that while `0.1+0.3 gives 0.4`, `0.1+0.2=0.30000000000000004`. Setting the key to `null` or `undefined` is another non sense that Javascript let's you do.

Answer (score 10):

I guess the whole point of Maps/Dictionaries is that you can use **objects** as keys in them, so:

```
let a = {}, b = {}, m = new Map();

m.set(a,b);
m.get(a); // b
```

So you get `b` since you have a **reference** on `a`. Let's say you serialize the Map by creating an Array of arrays, and stringify that to json:

```
function serialize (map) {
  return JSON.stringify([...map.entries()])
}

let s = serialize(m); // '[[{}, {}]]'
                      // '[[<key>, <val>], … ]'
```

Than you could:

```
let m2 = JSON.parse(s).reduce((m, [key, val])=> m.set(key, val) , new Map());
```

But the question now is: **How to get a certain key?** Since there does not exist any reference, due to the fact that all objects have been stringified and recreated, it is not possible to query a dedicated key.

So all that would only work for String keys, but that really takes most of power of maps, or in other words, reduces them to simple objects, what is the reason maps were implemented.

Comment: They have much more utility than just being able to use objects as keys They have the benefit of arrays being ordered, and the benefit of keys in objects, so you can get an item from the Map by a key, whether that is an object or a string, and you can loop a Map and be sure the items are in the right order.

Answer (score 2):

To @philipp's point, people who care about the serialization of the Map will probably prefer objects (leverages intuition, reduces '[]' arithmetic). [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) can make that a bit more literate:

```
writeMe = new Map()
writeMe.set('a', [1])
writeMe.set('b', {myObjValue: 2})
// ▶ Map(2) {'a' => Array(1), 'b' => {…}}

written = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(writeMe.entries()))
// '{"a":[1],"b":{"myObjValue":2}}'

read = new Map(Object.entries(JSON.parse(written)))
// ▶ Map(2) {'a' => Array(1), 'b' => {…}}

read.get("b")
// ▶ {myObjValue: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.js, this is a bit faster solution:

```js
import v8 from "node:v8"
// Preparing Data
const m = new Map()
// Serialization
const arrayBuffer = v8.serialize(m)
// Deserialization
const _m = v8.deserialize(arrayBuffer)
```

I'm getting half the time saved compared to JSON.stringify version, regardless of scaling (tested on simple "string => number" mapping). Not as huge as I expected, but you may get more benefit if your values stored in Map are complex.