# Why is this map empty after array.reduce

Tags: javascript

Why does this map print empty?  I'd expect it to be populated from the array?  I'm probably missing something small.

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];

let numberMap = numbers.reduce((map, obj) => {
  return map.set(obj, obj + 1);
}, new Map());

console.log(JSON.stringify(numberMap));
```

Comment: **It isn't**, but it looks that way when you log it because `Map` objects don't store their elements as object properties. `JSON.stringify` only includes own, enumerable properties, but `Map` entries aren't properties, so it looks empty. Instead: `console.log(JSON.stringify([...numberMap.entries()]))`.

Comment: There's an original question on here about this, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Could it be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153172/how-to-serialize-a-map-in-javascript) one?

Comment: @DavidFontes - Good find. I've added it to the list. :-)

Comment: JSON can only represent a subset of what a JS value can contain. The default representation of `console.log` is a lot better for that. If you'd drop the `JSON.stringify`, you'd see the elements in the output.

Comment: @CherryDT - Indeed. Although then you do have to worry about the [whole deferred evaluation thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection). :-D *(But it can be useful, too.)*