# Send Map in express res.send

Tags: javascript, express

I'm working on a game with a friend and we need to send a Map with some stuff in it, but express only sends the user `{}` instead of the actual Map. The problem is at sending it and not the code itself, `console.log`'ging it does return the Map.
Code:

```js
router.get("/list", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const users = await userCollection.find();
        accessedListEmbed(req);
        let userData = new Map();
        users.forEach((user) => userData.set(user.userName, user.status));
        res.send(userData);
        console.log(userData);
    } catch (error) {
        res.send("unknown");
    }
});
```

[image: Console output]
[image: Express respond (client used doesn't change anything)]

Comment: you need to serialize the Map first, one example is [`res.send(Array.from(userData.entries()))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61671167/28004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can only send serializable values over the network. Maps aren't serializable:

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set('key', 'value');
console.log(JSON.stringify(map));
```

Either send an array of arrays that can be converted into a Map on the client side, or use another data structure, like a plain object. For example:

```
router.get("/list", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const users = await userCollection.find();
        accessedListEmbed(req);
        const userDataArr = [];
        users.forEach((user) => {
            userDataArr.push([user.userName, user.status]);
        });
        res.json(userDataArr); // make sure to use .json
    } catch (error) {
        // send JSON in the case of an error too so it can be predictably parsed
        res.json({ error: error.message });
    }
});
```

Then on the client-side:

```
fetch(..)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        if ('error' in result) {
            // do something with result.error and return
        }
        const userDataMap = new Map(result);
        // ...
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Some unfortunate wording used in this answer.  Your first sentence should just say that a `Map` is not a supported data type for JSON and it has no default JSON conversion, so you have to convert it to something that JSON does support.  Maps absolutely are serializable, just not automatically by `JSON.stringify()`.