# I am using in puppeeter an evaluate and I try to pass a function to it, I am getting "myFunction is not a function"

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Basically, I have a function:

```
const parseToNumber = (inputString) => {
   const cleanedString = inputString.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]+/g, '');
   const numberValue = parseInt(cleanedString);
   return numberValue;
}
```

I'm trying to pass it to the evaluate method:

```
const parseToNumber = (inputString) => {
   const cleanedString = inputString.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]+/g, '');
   const numberValue = parseInt(cleanedString);
   return numberValue;
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> parseToNumber is not a function

what am I doing wrong?

```
async function getData(){
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 100,
    defaultViewport: {
        width: 1280,
        height: 1024,
    },
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    const url= "MY_URL";
    await  page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle0",
    });

    await page.evaluate(async (parseToNumber)=>{
       parseToNumber("2,42$");
    },parseToNumber);

 })
 .catch((err) => console.log("error loading url", err));

}
getData()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a function directly into `page.evaluate()`, but you can call another special method (`page.exposeFunction`), which expose your function as a global function (also available in as an attribute of your page `window` object), so you can call it when you are inside `page.evaluate()`:

```
var myFunc = function() { console.log("test"); };
await page.exposeFunction("myFunc", myFunc);

await page.evaluate(async () => {
   await myFunc();
   return true;
});
```

Answer taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304665/how-to-pass-a-function-in-puppeteers-evaluate-method) question, you can find a more in-depth discussion there.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

You need to stringify the function and then eval it back as a function inside the evaulate method:

```
await page.evaluate(async (parseToNumber) => {
    const parseToNumberFn = eval(parseToNumber)
    parseToNumberFn("2,42$");
}, parseToNumber.toString())
```

Comment: same error.....

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated the code. I forgot to store the evaluated function in a variable.
Since it is an arrow function, the function has no name