trying to print to command line in puppeteer from within page.evaluate
I am very new to puppeteer. I have a puppeteer script (node v20.15.0) and I'm trying to write/print to the command line from inside a page.evaluate that's inside an async function. I was following this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61336937/1827764
If I run that code, it works perfectly. I can even modify it to pass a variable like this:
await page.exposeFunction("myFunc", (value) => console.log(value));
await page.evaluate(async () => {
    await myFunc('test');
       return true;
});

However, I have something like this:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs'); //filesystem functions
const path = require('path'); //path-related functions
const https = require('https')

process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception) {
  console.log(exception); 
});

(async () => {
    var browser;

    var puppeteer_options = {
        headless: true, 
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, 
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--single-process', '--no-zygote', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--shm-size=4gb', ], 
        defaultViewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080},
        protocolTimeout: 1000000, //https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.LaunchOptions.html
    }

    browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppeteer_options);

    var page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.exposeFunction("logInNodeJs", (value) => console.log(value));

    var gp_args = {}
    gp_args['x_data'] = {}
    if(gp_args['x_data'])
    {
        var x = await get_x({x_data: gp_args['x_data'], gp_args:gp_args})
    }

    async function get_x(options)
    {
        var url = '<url>'

        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)

        await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

        gp_args['waitforselector'] = "div[class='paging']"
        gp_args['waitforselector_timeout'] = 30000

        try
        {

            await page.waitForSelector(gp_args['waitforselector'], {visible: true, timeout: gp_args['waitforselector_timeout'] })

        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(err)
            return
        }
    
        var el = await page.evaluate(async () => {
            await logInNodeJs('test 1')
        
            var el = document.querySelector("div[class='paging']")
        
            pages = el.querySelectorAll('a')
            return pages.length - 1
        })
        
        console.log(el)
    }
})()

In this example, when the "await logInNodeJs('test 1')" runs, the only output I get is:
[
just a left bracket. I don't know why it isn't printing out 'test 1', and I don't know where the "[" is coming from.

await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0) can hang your script forever and stifle errors. Never use this--set it to a few minutes, then throw so you know you need to fix something in your script. What exactly are you trying to do here? I almost never use exposeFunction--it's often not the best way to achieve whatever the real goal is. As well as providing your real goal, always provide either var url = '<url>', even if it's a sample page, so the code is runnable and reproducible. Thanks.

When I strip out all of the unrunnable/unreproducible bits, none of which should interfere with the logging, this works fine for me. I see test 1 printed and no [.

@ggorlen I'm trying to print output to the command line as the script is running from within page.evaluate. Since you can't just console.log() inside page.evaluate, I was exploring other options. The script in the link I included at the top works perfectly, so I know that it should be possible to do it.

You can totally console.log inside page.evaluate. But most people don't write scripts to do just that. They're usually trying to do something else more interesting and logging is just a means to some greater end. At any rate, the problem isn't reproducible here even taken at face value.
