# How can I dynamically inject functions to evaluate using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, headless-browser, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) for headless Chrome. I wish to evaluate a function inside the page that uses parts of other functions, defined dynamically elsewhere.

The code  below is a minimal example / proof. In reality `functionToInject()` and `otherFunctionToInject()` are more complex and require the pages DOM.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(someURL);       

var functionToInject = function(){
    return 1+1;
}

var otherFunctionToInject = function(input){
    return 6
}

var data = await page.evaluate(function(functionToInject, otherFunctionToInject){
    console.log('woo I run inside a browser')
    return functionToInject() + otherFunctionToInject();
});

return data
```

When I run the code, I get:

> Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: functionToInject is not a function

Which I understand: `functionToInject` isn't being passed into the page's JS context. But how do I pass it into the page's JS context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a function in Puppeteers .evaluate() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304665/how-to-pass-a-function-in-puppeteers-evaluate-method)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can add function to page context with [`addScriptTag`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageaddscripttagoptions):

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

function functionToInject (){
    return 1+1;
}

function otherFunctionToInject(input){
    return 6
}

await page.addScriptTag({ content: `${functionToInject} ${otherFunctionToInject}`});

var data = await page.evaluate(function(){
    console.log('woo I run inside a browser')
    return functionToInject() + otherFunctionToInject();
});

console.log(data);

await browser.close();
```

This example is a dirty way of solving this problem with string concatenation. More clean would be using a `url` or `path` in the `addScriptTag` method.

---

Or use [`exposeFunction`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) (but now functions are wrapped in Promise):

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

var functionToInject = function(){
    return 1+1;
}

var otherFunctionToInject = function(input){
    return 6
}

await page.exposeFunction('functionToInject', functionToInject);
await page.exposeFunction('otherFunctionToInject', otherFunctionToInject);

var data = await page.evaluate(async function(){
    console.log('woo I run inside a browser')
    return await functionToInject() + await otherFunctionToInject();
});

console.log(data);

await browser.close();
```

Comment: I don't know - I never use it in that way. I've added another solution with `exposeFunction`.

Comment: I know a thanks isn't necessary but just wanted to say it anyway - this is a really comprehensive answer with exampels and links to docs.

Comment: Also `path` looks good for `addScriptTag` - no need for a custom URL schema to keep injected content seperate.

Comment: It is good to know that with the first method (addScriptTag), the function executes within the browser. With the second method (exposeFunction) the function executes in Node.js. If you need to pass DOM elements to the function, the first method is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

working example [accessible by link](https://github.com/KEMBL/StencilJs.playground/blob/2b5053798af3d796b9aaba273bb505236240ddfa/src/components/OptionsList/ListOption/list-option.e2e.tsx#L22), in the same repo you can see the tested component.

```js
it("click should return option value", async () => {
    const optionToReturn = "ClickedOption";

    const page = await newE2EPage();
    const mockCallBack = jest.fn();

    await page.setContent(
      `<list-option option='${optionToReturn}'></list-option>`
    );

    await page.exposeFunction("functionToInject", mockCallBack); // Inject function
    await page.$eval("list-option", (elm: any) => {
      elm.onOptionSelected = this.functionToInject;  // Assign function
    });
    await page.waitForChanges();

    const element = await page.find("list-option");
    await element.click();
    expect(mockCallBack.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1); // Check calls
    expect(mockCallBack.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(optionToReturn); // Check argument
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `page.exposeFunction()` which will make your function return a `Promise` (requiring the use of `async` and `await`). This happens because your function will not be [running inside your browser](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction), but inside your `nodejs` application and its results are being send back and forth into/to the browser code.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(someURL);       

var functionToInject = function(){
    return 1+1;
}

var otherFunctionToInject = function(input){
    return 6
}

await page.exposeFunction("functionToInject", functionToInject)
await page.exposeFunction("otherFunctionToInject", otherFunctionToInject)

var data = await page.evaluate(async function(){
    console.log('woo I run inside a browser')
    return await functionToInject() + await otherFunctionToInject();
});

return data
```

Related questions:

1. [exposeFunction() does not work after goto()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2170)
2. [exposed function queryseldtcor not working in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772855/exposed-function-queryseldtcor-not-working-in-puppeteer)
3. [How to use evaluateOnNewDocument and exposeFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113267/how-to-use-evaluateonnewdocument-and-exposefunction)
4. [exposeFunction remains in memory?](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3961)
5. [Puppeteer: pass variable in .evaluate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/puppeteer-pass-variable-in-evaluate)
6. [Puppeteer evaluate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904333/puppeteer-evaluate-function)
7. [allow to pass a parameterized funciton as a string to page.evaluate](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/982)
8. [Functions bound with page.exposeFunction() produce unhandled promise rejections](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3549)
9. [How to pass a function in Puppeteers .evaluate() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304665/how-to-pass-a-function-in-puppeteers-evaluate-method)
10. [Why can't I access 'window' in an exposeFunction() function with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281130/why-cant-i-access-window-in-an-exposefunction-function-with-puppeteer)