# Why can't I access 'window' in an exposeFunction() function with Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, headless-browser, puppeteer

I have a very simple [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) script that uses [`exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to run something inside headless Chrome.

```
(async function(){

    var log = console.log.bind(console),
        puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    var functionToInject = function(){
        return window.navigator.appName;
    }

    await page.exposeFunction('functionToInject', functionToInject);

    var data = await page.evaluate(async function(){
        console.log('woo I run inside a browser')
        return await functionToInject();
    });

    console.log(data);

    await browser.close();

})()
```

This fails with:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Which refers to the injected function. How can I access `window` inside the headless Chrome?

I know I can do `evaluate()` instead, but this doesn't work with a function I pass dynamically:

```
(async function(){

    var log = console.log.bind(console),
        puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    var data = await page.evaluate(async function(){
        console.log('woo I run inside a browser')
        return window.navigator.appName;
    });

    console.log(data);

    await browser.close();

})()
```

Comment: I am not so sure why this is happening, but you can pass `window` as a variable and use it in your function.

Comment: Are you sure? `Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: What do you mean by second script not working? Does it throw the same error as the first one?

Answer (score 25):

#### `evaluate` the function

You can pass the **dynamic script** using `evaluate`.

```
(async function(){
    var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    var functionToInject = function(){
        return window.navigator.appName;
    }

    var data = await page.evaluate(functionToInject); // <-- Just pass the function
    console.log(data); // outputs: Netscape
    
    await browser.close();
})()
```

#### `addScriptTag` and `readFileSync`

You can save the function to a seperate file and use the function using `addScriptTag`.

```
await page.addScriptTag({path: 'my-script.js'});
```

or `evaluate` with `readFileSync`.

```
await page.evaluate(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'));
```

or, pass a parameterized funciton as a string to `page.evaluate`.

```
await page.evaluate(new Function('foo', 'console.log(foo);'), {foo: 'bar'});
```

#### Make a new function dynamically

How about making it into a `runnable` function :D ?

```
function runnable(fn) {
  return new Function("arguments", `return ${fn.toString()}(arguments)`);
}
```

The above will create a new function with provided arguments. We can pass any function we want.

Such as the following function with `window`, along with arguments,

```
function functionToInject() {
  return window.location.href;
};
```

works flawlessly with promises too,

```
function functionToInject() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(window.location.href);
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

and with arguments,

```
async function functionToInject(someargs) {
  return someargs; // {bar: 'foo'}
};
```

Call the desired function with `evaluate`,

```
var data = await page.evaluate(runnable(functionToInject), {bar: "foo"});
console.log(data); // shows the location
```

Comment: This is best solution so far. the `await page.evaluate(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'));` works at best allowing some structure in the code

Answer (score 15):

`exposeFunction()` isn't the right tool for this job.

From the [Puppeteer docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

> page.exposeFunction(name, puppeteerFunction)
>
> puppeteerFunction  Callback function which will be called **in Puppeteer's context**.

'In puppeteer's context' is a little vague, but check out the docs for `evaluate()`:

> page.evaluateHandle(pageFunction, ...args)
>
> pageFunction  Function to be evaluated **in the page context**

`exposeFunction()` doesn't expose a function to run inside the page, but exposes a function to be be run in node **to be called** from the page.

I have to use `evaluate()`:

Comment: hi, I've encountered the same problem and I was wondering if you managed to find a better solution than page.evaluate?

Comment: How did your code became not you are using `evaluate`?

Answer (score 3):

You problem could be related to the fact that `page.exposeFunction()` will make your function return a `Promise` (requiring the use of `async` and `await`). This happens because your function will not be [running inside your browser](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction), but inside your `nodejs` application and its results are being send back and forth into/to the browser code. This is why you function passed to `page.exposeFunction()` is now returning a promise instead of the actual result. And it explains why the `window` function is not defined, because your function is running inside `nodejs` (not your browser) and inside `nodejs` there is no `window` definition available.

Related questions:

1. [exposeFunction() does not work after goto()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2170)
2. [exposed function queryseldtcor not working in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772855/exposed-function-queryseldtcor-not-working-in-puppeteer)
3. [How to use evaluateOnNewDocument and exposeFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113267/how-to-use-evaluateonnewdocument-and-exposefunction)
4. [exposeFunction remains in memory?](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3961)
5. [Puppeteer: pass variable in .evaluate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/puppeteer-pass-variable-in-evaluate)
6. [Puppeteer evaluate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904333/puppeteer-evaluate-function)
7. [allow to pass a parameterized funciton as a string to page.evaluate](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/982)
8. [Functions bound with page.exposeFunction() produce unhandled promise rejections](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3549)
9. [How to pass a function in Puppeteers .evaluate() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304665/how-to-pass-a-function-in-puppeteers-evaluate-method)
10. [How can I dynamically inject functions to evaluate using Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207414/how-can-i-dynamically-inject-functions-to-evaluate-using-puppeteer)