# Puppeteer - Error: window is not defined - in page.evaluate nested function

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I was given a test code, which I am not allowed to change, but only implementing it using Puppeteer (and other libraries if necessary).

This is the code I received:

```
// this code is given And can't be changed!
assertOnLeft(function (asserter) {
        asserter(window.location.href.indexOf("XXX:3000/regression_test_pages/links_page.html") == 0,
         "Address should be links_page.html");
});
```

I tried to implement it this way:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const assertOnLeft = async (predicate) => {
const asserterOk = assert.ok;

await page.exposeFunction("predicate", predicate);
await page.evaluate((asserterOk) => { // creates Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: window is not defined
    return predicate(asserterOk)
    }, asserterOk).catch((e) => console.log("error", e));
}
```

but I get an error:

```
error Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I tried to pass the function directly as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281130/why-cant-i-access-window-in-an-exposefunction-function-with-puppeteer)

> return await page.evaluate(predicate(assert.ok))

or

> var runnable = predicate(assert.ok);
> return await page.evaluate(runnable);

But still get the same error, probably because I am sending a function that cal's a function, as a parameter to page.evaluate

Thanks

Comment: Have you gone through this thread?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281130/why-cant-i-access-window-in-an-exposefunction-function-with-puppeteer

Comment: Yes. I also edited my question as referenced to their suggestions.

Comment: But you're still trying to access `window` from Node. That won't work, as the link states.