# Exposed function querySelector not working in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

```
document.querySelectorAll('.summary').innerText;
```

This throws an error in the below snippet saying "document.querySelector is not a function" in my Puppeteer page's exposed fucntion `docTest`.

I want to pass a specific node to each method and get the result inside `evaluate`.

Same with `document.getElemenetbyId`.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
//var querySelectorAll = require('query-selector');


let docTest = (document) => {
var summary = document.querySelectorAll(.summary).innerText;
console.log(summary);
return summary;
}

let scrape = async () => {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('http://localhost.com:80/static.html');
await page.waitFor(5000)
await page.exposeFunction('docTest', docTest);

var result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    var resultworking = document.querySelector("tr");
    console.log(resultworking);
    var summary  = docTest(document);
    console.log(resultworking);
    return summary;

});
console.log(result);

await page.waitFor(7000);
browser.close();
return {
    result
}
};

scrape().then((value) => {
console.log(value); // Success!
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I access 'window' in an exposeFunction() function with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281130/why-cant-i-access-window-in-an-exposefunction-function-with-puppeteer)

Comment: Don't forget to `await browser.close()`, `page.waitFor(7000);` is deprecated. It's good to use a `finally` block to close the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same question. The problem is that the `page.evaluate()` function callback has to be an `async` function and your function `docTest()` will return a `Promise` when called inside the `page.evaluate()`. To fix it, just add the `async` and `await` keywords to your code:

```js
await page.exposeFunction('docTest', docTest);

var result = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    var summary = await docTest(document);
    console.log(summary);
    return summary;
});
```

Just remember that `page.exposeFunction()` will make your function return a `Promise`, then, you need to use `async` and `await`. This happens because your function will not be [running inside your browser](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction), but inside your `nodejs` application.

1. [exposeFunction() does not work after goto()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2170)
2. [Why can't I access 'window' in an exposeFunction() function with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281130/why-cant-i-access-window-in-an-exposefunction-function-with-puppeteer)
3. [How to use evaluateOnNewDocument and exposeFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113267/how-to-use-evaluateonnewdocument-and-exposefunction)
4. [exposeFunction remains in memory?](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3961)
5. [Puppeteer: pass variable in .evaluate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/puppeteer-pass-variable-in-evaluate)
6. [Puppeteer evaluate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904333/puppeteer-evaluate-function)
7. [allow to pass a parameterized funciton as a string to page.evaluate](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/982)
8. [Functions bound with page.exposeFunction() produce unhandled promise rejections](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3549)
9. [How to pass a function in Puppeteers .evaluate() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304665/how-to-pass-a-function-in-puppeteers-evaluate-method)
10. [How can I dynamically inject functions to evaluate using Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207414/how-can-i-dynamically-inject-functions-to-evaluate-using-puppeteer)

Comment: This exact example gives me `document2.createElement is not a function at document` when i run it, any ideas why?